# how to store more than 1 item in a single column in SQL table

Tags: java, mysql

i have this data

```
searchterm=mobile
frequency=43200
catName=-1
showNowPageSize=100
showNowPageNumber=1
```

which i am trying to save in my SQL column "queryparams"

is this possible to save the whole data in a single column , if yes How?  and what should be this queryparams  in SQL , will it be varchar?

right now i am getting this exception :

> Data truncation: Data too long for column 'queryparams' at row 1

thanks

Comment: Well, obviously your column is probably of type varchar with a length smaller than the length you are trying to put in to. You'll have to make your column size larger of make it of type 'blob' and I would just serialize your data. (I am no java expert so I'll leave it to them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you must make the column wide enough. Try a `CLOB` field type instead. Only this will cause other problems in the future.

The correct solution for 1:N problems (one node with several children) is to use a foreign key.

Create a table `queryparams` with these columns `ID, QUERY, INDEX, NAME, VALUE`

The `INDEX` is only necessary if you need to preserve the ordering of query parameters. The `QUERY` column is a foreign key: It's the primary key of the query node to which these parameters belong.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, if you serialize the data to a string (for example, JSON) but it would be incorrect in my opinion, use the power of the DB and separate the data to different columns (it should work most of the time)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just store it as a query string in that case.

```
"searchterm=mobile&frequency=43200&catName=-1&showNowPageSize=100&showNowPageNumber=1"
```

Just store it in a normal varchar column.

However, if you need to query based on any of those values or they have significance for analytical or data-mining purposes, you should normalize the parameters, either into discrete columns or into a name/value pair table.

Answer (score 0):

IT seems that you declared your column type to a type that is not bg enough to your purpose. If you really want to do what you explained, you should use a longer type. Then use a separator, whichever you want, some character or character sequence that is not possible in your data.

However, I seecond @Binyamin Sharet, columns are not meant to be a put-whatever-you-think-is-good in a column, you ought probably better use several columns for several informations. The cleaner the better, a clean design offers better opportunities for improvement and features...even if it seems to be quite incompatible with a productivist-and-capitalistic short term approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a object/struct out of it and serialize it to a Blob field.